# How do I analyze the correlation of set of points to this complicated parametric equation?

Tags: analysis, statistics, parametric, correlation, data-analysis

I am trying to quantify the correlation of a given set of points to the set of points defined by a parametric equation, as well as find the best $l$ to fit the points. However, I am unsure of how to go about doing this.

The parametric equation I am working with is 
$$x(a)=a\ln \left(\frac{l+\sqrt{l^2+a^2}}{a}\right)$$
$$y(a)=\sqrt{l^2+a^2}-a.$$

I have found $l\approx.373$. The range of the parameter $a$ is $0\lt a \lt \infty$.

The set of points I am trying to analyze is
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \style{font-family:inherit}{x} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{y}}\\\hline
 .372 & .017  \\\hline
 .343 & .125  \\\hline
 .308 & .184  \\\hline
 .267 & .232  \\\hline
 .234 & .262  \\\hline
 .192 & .293  \\\hline
 .147 & .320  \\\hline
 .110 & .338  \\\hline
 .065 & .356  \\\hline
 .030 & .367  \\\hline
 .003 & .372
\end{array}

A plot of the parametric equation and the set of points suggests a strong correlation for $l\approx.373$. Here is a graph on Desmos showing this: [parametric equation and plotted points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Dc6.png) (The parametric equation is in red and the data points are plotted in black).

Typically, when finding the correlation between a function and a plot of points, the plot is linearized as the function indicates and a linear regression is run to evaluate the correlation. Unfortunately, I have found no way to linearize the set of points. Are there any other ways to find the parametric curve of best fit?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Did you try the mean squared error? Why does/doesn't that work? **Edit:** I suppose calculating the residuals, and thus the mean squared error, ultimately involves choosing some statistical model for the points (e.g. maybe observed $\hat{x}$ is equal to $x(a) + \varepsilon_a$ with $\varepsilon_a$ independent random variables). Also I feel like you might get better answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ , but it might make sense to wait a week here before reposting there, to avoid getting downvoted or yelled at in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question! My original question wasn't so clear. I also wanted to find $l$ that best fits the points, but Claude Leibovici has answered this adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting the data, just as you did, reveals the strong relation between $x$ and $y$.

Now, what I suspect is that they want you to find the best value of $l$ to improve the fit.

It is impossible to get rid of the parametrization in order to have $y=f(x)$. However, you can do the opposite.

Eliminate $a$ from $y$
$$a=\frac{l^2-y^2}{2 y}\qquad \implies \qquad x=\frac{(l^2-y^2) }{2 y}\,\log \left(\frac{l+y}{l-y}\right)$$

Using the starting value you gave, a basic nonlinear regression gives
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 l & 0.372631 & 0.000115 & \{0.37237,0.372892\} \\
\end{array}$$ and you can notice that $0.373$ is not in the confidence interval (even if very close to it).

For sure, this introduces a bias in the problem since what has been measured is $y$ and not $x$.

To compensate, I think that I should use orthogonal regression (total least squares).